# MYSQL getting poll results table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one with poll answers and one with votes:

```
DESC polls;

Field   Type      Null  Key Default Extra
id      int(11)   NO    PRI NULL    auto_increment
pollId  int(11)   NO    MUL NULL    
answer  varchar(150)    YES NULL    

DESC votes;
Field    Type      Null Key Default Extra
id       int(11)    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
pollId   int(11)    NO  MUL NULL    
answerId int(11)    NO  MUL NULL    
userId   int(11)    NO  MUL NULL
```

I am trying to get following results with all answers and votes:

```
pollId answerId numberOfVotes
1        1          20
1        2          10
1        3          0
```

I tried right joins of votes to answers, but it does not work:

```
SELECT answers.id, COUNT(votes.answerId) FROM answers JOIN votes ON votes.pollId = answers.pollId GROUP BY votes.pollId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7526565ac9c77d379d5477dff6b01f70)**

```
SELECT polls.pollId,polls.id,COUNT(userid) as counts
FROM polls left JOIN votes ON votes.pollId = polls.pollId and 
polls.id=votes.answerId
GROUP BY polls.pollId,polls.id order by polls.id
```

OUTPUT:

```
pollId  id  counts
14      17  0
14      18  2
14      19  0
14      20  0
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives me incorrect result where it says that answers with 0 votes have votes.

Comment: can u add some sample data then it'll be easy to get it @NodirNasirov

Comment: `select * from answers;
id pollId answer
17  14  black
18  14  brown
19  14  white
20  14  bold

select * from votes;
id  pollId answerId userId
5     14     18      3
6     14     18      2`

Comment: @NodirNasirov, and from this rows what is your expected output?

Comment: `answerId countVotes
17        0
18        2
19        0
20        0`

Comment: @NodirNasirov, I've changed the answer - you can check